Non linear eigenvalue problem for spinor Hartree-Fock equation
Today I have a couple of eigenvalue differential equations for $f(r)$ and $g(r)$ (square integrable complex functions with $r > 0$):
$$ \left( - \frac{\Delta_r}{2} - Z/r + \frac{1}{2} h_0(\vert f \vert^2 + \vert g \vert^2) \right) f - h_0(f g^*) g = k f $$
$$ \left( - \frac{\Delta_r}{2} - Z/r + \frac{1}{2} h_0(\vert f \vert^2 + \vert g \vert^2) \right) g - h_0(f^* g) f = k g $$
$Z$ integer (i.e number of protons) with:
$$ \Delta_r = \frac{1}{r^2} \partial_r r^2 \partial_r $$
$$ h_0(F) = \frac{1}{r} \int_0^r F(u) u^2 d u + \int_r^{\infty} u F(u) d u $$ $$\int_0^{\infty} r^2 (\vert f \vert^2 + \vert g \vert^2) d r = 1$$
$$\int_0^{\infty} r^2 f^* g d r = \int_0^{\infty} r^2 f g^* d r = 0$$
Question:
What is the configuration for $(f,g)$ to get the minimum value of $k$ (i.e finding the ground state in quantum mechanics)?
Hint:
Using variational principle I have found at the moment that $g = 0$ and $f$ real was the eigenfunctions pair with the lowest eigenvalue $k$ (i.e $\simeq -2.8616/2$ see Ludena article on Hartree equation). But I am not sure... since a couple of complex function (f,g) could also form a minimum for $k$ (why not?).
EDIT:
There is just one $k$, not $k_f$ and $k_g$, I apologize
